# plt.hist errors on subsetted data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, seaborn

I'm very new to Python so please excuse any stupidity on my part.

I'm running a histogram with matplotlib and getting errors when I use subset data, the code works perfectly if I use the full dataset, hence my confusion.

Perhaps I'm not subsetting correctly?

My code is below and related errors are below, thanks.

- For awareness, this was written in Python 3.

Import required packages:

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import seaborn as sns
```

Read the data:

```
mlb=pd.read_csv('C:\Users\ocmh\Desktop\Python\Batting.csv')
```

View a sample of the data:

```
mlb.head()
```

Subset the data to return just Boston data:

```
mlb_bos=mlb[(mlb['teamID'] == 'BOS')]
```

View a sample of the subset data:

```
mlb_bos.head()
```

Plot a histogram of the original data:  And works perfectly

```
plt.hist(mlb.AB.dropna, color= sns.desaturate("indianred",1))
```

Plot a histogram of the subset data:  Returns errors (Errors are below)

```
plt.hist(mlb_bos.AB.dropna, color= sns.desaturate("indianred",1))
```

If you don't have the seaborn package installed, you can just drop color= sns.desaturate("indianred",1) as this was purely for aesthetics.

Errors below:

---

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-11-1484047d7ac6> in <module>()

----> 1 plt.hist(mlb_bos.AB, color=color)



/Users/mattoconnell/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in hist(x, bins, range, normed, weights, cumulative, bottom, histtype, align, orientation, rwidth, log, color, label, stacked, hold, **kwargs)

   2894                       histtype=histtype, align=align, orientation=orientation,

   2895                       rwidth=rwidth, log=log, color=color, label=label,

-> 2896                       stacked=stacked, **kwargs)

   2897         draw_if_interactive()

   2898     finally:



/Users/mattoconnell/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py in hist(self, x, bins, range, normed, weights, cumulative, bottom, histtype, align, orientation, rwidth, log, color, label, stacked, **kwargs)

   5602         # Massage 'x' for processing.

   5603         # NOTE: Be sure any changes here is also done below to 'weights'

-> 5604         if isinstance(x, np.ndarray) or not iterable(x[0]):

   5605             # TODO: support masked arrays;

   5606             x = np.asarray(x)



/Users/mattoconnell/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in __getitem__(self, key)

    512     def __getitem__(self, key):

    513         try:

--> 514             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)

    515

    516             if not np.isscalar(result):



/Users/mattoconnell/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/index.py in get_value(self, series, key)

   1458

   1459         try:

-> 1460             return self._engine.get_value(s, k)

   1461         except KeyError as e1:

   1462             if len(self) > 0 and self.inferred_type in ['integer','boolean']:



pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/index.c:3113)()



pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/index.c:2844)()



pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3704)()



pandas/hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:7255)()



pandas/hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:7193)()



KeyError: 0
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be`mlb_bos=mlb[mlb['teamID'] == 'BOS']`

Comment: After subsetting, you may have to use `plt.hist(mlb_bos.AB.values, color=color)` to avoid this exception.

Comment: Thanks. As soon as I can get logged on I will try both suggestions